# Finding the jones polynomial of the following knot

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I am struggling with finding the Jones polynomial of the following knot

[image]

using only the *sklein relations*

[image]

I am also asked if it is Isotopic to its mirror image. I tried using the above relation, but got nothing similar to what wikipedia gives. Is there a simpler way to obtain the Jones polynomial ?

Comment: Did you try baby steps? i.e. start by computing the disjoint union of $n$ circles, and then try to see what happens when you add some crossings here and there? Tip : Taking two disjoint circles in $) ($ shape and switching the crossing still gives you a circle.

Comment: I tried using $(2)$ on $6_2$ until I got the $(1)$ case or the hopf link. Seems like it is enough with two splits.

Comment: So I assume you're good to go?

Comment: No good for showing you how to do it, but if you want to check your answer you can always try: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maaac/KnotProgram/index_ns.html
I just typed in your knot and got 
V(t) = t^-5 - 2t^-4 + 2t^-3 - 2t^-2 + 2t^-1 -1 + t